# Apache Beam GroupByKey never fires when using DirectRunner

Tags: apache-beam

The title pretty much sums it all. No matter how short I set the window width, `GroupByKey` never fires when running the job on DirectRunner. Everything works as expected when using DataflowRunner.

Comment: Is there any update to this issue? I'm observing the same behaviour in beam 2.5.0

Comment: Not until the last time I checked. I resorted to running it on Dataflow runner.

Answer (score 6):

`GroupByKey` by default fires a particular window when the watermark of the input `PCollection` reaches the end of that window. If it's not firing, that means that the watermark of the input `PCollection` is not advancing, or perhaps it is advancing but all your data ends up being discarded as late.

The reasons for that depend on how the `PCollection` is produced. My guess would be that you might be reading it directly from `PubSubIO.read()`. Computing the watermark for PubSub is challenging (especially if you're using a custom timestamp attribute); there are some known issues with this computation in Direct runner; Dataflow runner substitutes a different implementation at runtime that computes the watermark more accurately (but still imperfectly).

Unfortunately, we currently lack tools for monitoring the progress of a watermark in direct runner. You could try debugging this by adding some log statements to `PubsubUnboundedSource.PubsubReader.getWatermark()`. You also could add a `ParDo` between the read and the GBK and print out the event-time timestamps you end up receiving (`c.timestamp()`).

You can also try configuring the windowing strategy to not drop late data, see [Managing late data](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#managing-late-data).